# Left Join with Count from different table

Tags: mysql, count, left-join

Tables - I have removed additional fields not needed for the query:

```
church (id, name)
delegate (id, orderId, churchId, status)
orders (id, eventId)
event (id, name)
```

The variable ddEvent gets included at run time with the name of the event (not the eventId)

I would like a complete list of church names with the number of delegates (if any) going to a particular event who have a status of 'Paid', 'Started' or 'Completed'

I have tried this:

```
select church.name as 'Church Name', count(delegate.id) as Delegates
from church
left join delegate on church.id = delegate.churchId and (delegate.status = 'Paid' or delegate.status = 'Started' or delegate.status = 'Completed')
join orders on delegate.orderId = orders.id
join event on orders.eventId = event.id AND event.Name = 'ddEvent'
group by church.id
```

However this doesn't produce the correct result

Comment: have you tried to left join the orders and event tables?

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: What's wrong with your code?  If you don't tell what's wrong, what's to fix?

Comment: @NoveSanchez Is correct. You need to use `LEFT JOIN` for all the tables that are dependent on a table that you're `LEFT JOIN`ing. You should post it as an answer.

Comment: Thank you for your replies. I have tried LEFT JOIN however this gives all of the delegates that are booked. The event.Name criteria doesn't get applied. My query in the question correctly applies the event.Name criteria but doesn't list all the churches regardless of if there are bookings made

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to count the number of delegates that attended a certain event, then you cannot do a left join between the delegates down to the event. Those joins need to be inner joins.

What you must do is to play around the **order** of the joins, to make sure that `delegate - orders - events` tables are inner joined first, and then their combined result is left joined on the `church`. You need to use parentheses in the `from` clause to achieve this:

```
select church.name as 'Church Name', count(delegate.id) as Delegates
from church
left join (delegate
           inner join orders on delegate.orderId = orders.id
           inner join event on orders.eventId = event.id AND event.Name = 'ddEvent')  on church.id = delegate.churchId and (delegate.status = 'Paid' or delegate.status = 'Started' or delegate.status = 'Completed')
group by church.id
```

Pls note how I moved the `on` clause joining the `church` table and the `delegate` table to the end of the `from` clause.

Comment: Brilliant, thank you. I had tried using a sub query (without joy). This now makes a lot more sense!

Answer (score 0):

Try doing a left join to the 2 dependent tables.

```
select church.name as 'Church Name', count(delegate.id) as Delegates 
from church 
left join delegate on church.id = delegate.churchId 
and (delegate.status = 'Paid' or delegate.status = 'Started' or delegate.status = 'Completed') 
left join orders on delegate.orderId = orders.id 
left join event on orders.eventId = event.id
where event.Name = 'ddEvent' 
group by church.id
```

@Barmar thank you!

Comment: Thank you for helping me. That was exactly what I thought I needed to do however, the event.Name criteria doesn't get applied. All delegates for all events get counted by church rather than being limited to just the single event I am interested in.

Comment: how about putting the condition of event.Name in a where clause to simply display the single event. i have edited the query above.

Comment: Unfortunately that stops the full list of churches being displayed. e.g. only those churches which have a booking made against them get included in the results list.